# is the username returned by graph facebook guaranteed to exist?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm develoving a facebook application, using [passport-facebook](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-facebook) as an interface to facebook oauth.

I want to know if is it guaranteed to exist a username for every facebook user, so I can safely expect to have a facebook username to save into my database to use as a default login username in my app.

ref: I couldn't find in [facebook's graph documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) the answer to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value you should save in your database is the user id because username can be easily changed by users.  https://www.facebook.com/help/162586890471598